# I can't install the ndiswrapped WG311v3 drivers

Tags: wireless, 64-bit, ndiswrapper

The instructions here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Netgear_WG311_v3 - work super well if you are using the i386 kernel, but I installed with Wubi which automatically selected the amd64 kernel even though I'm pretty sure my PC is not 64bit.

The thing is is that the driver will showed up as installed in my `ndiswrapper -l` list but `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` never amounts to anything.

Is there anything else I can try?

---

Fixed!

Finally got workable status using a Marvell driver from a German site!

http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/verbindungsprobleme-mit-wlan-marvel-8339-libe/#post-1888522

Then from there all I did was:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -r wg311v3
sudo ndiswrapper -i (the Marvell.inf)
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Et voila!

Comment: Answer your question with the solution you found and choose it as the correct answer. This will mark the question answered.

Answer (score 1):

From the solution mentioned by the original poster:

```
Finally got workable status using a Marvell driver from a German site!

http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/verbindungsprobleme-mit-wlan-marvel-8339-libe/#post-1888522

Then from there all I did was:

sudo ndiswrapper -r wg311v3
sudo ndiswrapper -i (the Marvell.inf)
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper 

Et voila!
```